# Saving a new entry in Excel VBA does not save the new entry

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code to Save a new entry. I display the record selected from the list box. When the user press 'Add New', I clear the text boxes and allow them to enter new data in the text boxes. When they press 'Save', only the first text box (membership no) is saved with new value. All the columns take the value of the record which was displayed before the user press 'Add New' button.

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim newrow As Long
    Set ws = Worksheets("Master")

    newrow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("A:A")) + 1

    ws.Cells(newrow, 1).Value = Me.txtMembershipNo.Value
    ws.Cells(newrow, 2).Value = Me.txtName.Value
    ws.Cells(newrow, 3).Value = Me.txtAddress.Value
    ws.Cells(newrow, 4).Value = Me.cmboxState.Value
    ws.Cells(newrow, 5).Value = Me.cmboxCategory.Value
    ws.Cells(newrow, 6).Value = Me.cmboxType.Value
    ws.Cells(newrow, 7).Value = Me.cmboxStatus.Value
    ws.Cells(newrow, 8).Value = Me.txtRemarks.Value

    btnDelete.Enabled = True
    btnAddNew.Enabled = True
    btnUpdate.Enabled = False
    btnSave.Enabled = False
    btnCancel.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

[image]

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

    txtMembershipNo.Text = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 0)
    txtName.Text = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 1)
    txtAddress.Text = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 2)
    cmboxState.Text = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 3)
    cmboxCategory.Text = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 4)
    cmboxType.Text = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 5)
    cmboxStatus.Text = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 6)
    txtRemarks.Text = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 7)

    btnDelete.Enabled = True
    btnUpdate.Enabled = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What you describe should not be possible. Go through the code step by step using F8 and check the values of the text/combo boxes in each step. • Is your data in a formatted table (which has some kind of autofill enabled)? • Can you provide a screenshot of the data?

Comment: Sorry, how can i attach a screenshot here?

Comment: [Edit] your question and use the toolbar button for adding a picture.

Comment: Isn't this because of the `Me.` that only the first thing goes right?

Comment: @Luuklag Why? `Me` should refer either to the worksheet or to the userform, if I'm not totally wrong.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ not sure, but I don't like `Me.` as it is always implicitly. So you never really know what is happening.

Comment: @KKarunaharan Actually I thought of a screenshot of the worksheet (the one of the form isn't really helpful). And you should blur out the addresses in your screenshot if they are not fake addresses.

Comment: @Luuklag Actually it always refers to the class: [Me keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/me-keyword)

Comment: OK @Peh. I attached the screenshot of the worksheet.

Comment: Actually this should work as it is. Can you please test the following: Write a `Application.EnableEvents = False` before the first `ws.Cells` line and `Application.EnableEvents = True` behind the last `ws.Cells` line. Just to ensure that there are no other events interfering.

Comment: The first thing I would check is the value of "newrow".  Doing a Count on an entire column can be risky if there's ever a chance that something went wrong and you ended up with a value buried somewhere in the column.  I would set up your data as a Table and then do count on a Column within the Table.

Comment: @PEH, When I step through the code (F8), I noticed, after each line in 'Save' routine, it is going to my another routine where I load the data into the textboxes. This routine is executed twice before it returns to the next line in 'Save' routine. It is a kind of weird. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @PEH This happens even after I include Application.EnableEvents = False/True statements. Is Listbox_Click the right event to use?

Comment: @Frank the value of 'newrow' returns the correct value.

Comment: @KKarunaharan Actuall that is very weird and should not happen. Especially when `EnableEvents = False` so we can be sure no events are triggered. I have no idea how this could be caused. Try to do some more investigation (eg. disalbe code not needed) to narrow it down to some more specific point. • Also restart your computer and try it on another machine just to make sure it's not something odd with your computer.

Comment: Is Listbox_Click the right event? I tried with ListBox_DblClick, then it works fine.

Comment: Actually the `Listbox_Click` should only trigger on a click. And the ListBox is actually not involved at all in your `Save` procedure. That's really strange.

Comment: Is there any list box properties that I need to pay attention too?